# How to Rotate Canvas Context

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, rotation

How can I rotate a canvas object like -

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(52, 52, 53, 0.75)';
ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);
```

It doesn't need to be a loop, but how can I rotate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@M. Page's** answer does cause this to rotate, but not in the way you are probably thinking. In general `rotate()` is not about the middle point of your object, but another point `(0,0)`. To fix this we need to make our object's middle point to `(0,0)`, then do a rotation, then translate back. Like so:

```
ctx.translate((c.width/2) - 50, (c.height/2) - 50); // move back
ctx.rotate(20*Math.PI/180); // rotate
ctx.translate((-c.width/2) + 50, (-c.height/2) + 50); // move to 0,0
ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100); // Notice the middle point would be (x+50, y+50)
```

Notice that this is actually done from the bottom-up, which is how the stack for graphics work.

**[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/h15qowh1/)**, notice the difference if you comment the `translate()` out.

The `-50` and `+50` comes from placing the center of our box in the middle. Without them it will rotate about the bottom-right corner of the box and not the center of the box. To give a visual example:

- [**With the middle box point +50/-50**](http://jsfiddle.net/h15qowh1/1/)
- [**Without the +50/-50**](http://jsfiddle.net/h15qowh1/2/)

Basically we want to translate to the position where our box's mid-point is at `(0,0)`.

Comment: What is the +50 and -50 from?

Comment: @AlexSafayan because the middle point of our box is 50 pixels from the left corner on both sides. Otherwise it would rotate it about the top-left corner of the box.

Comment: @AlexSafayan I've updated my answer to show this clearly, the links have two animated rotations.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="134px" height="331px" onclick="draw()"></canvas> 
<script>
    var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(52, 52, 53, 0.75)';
    ctx.rotate(20*Math.PI/180);
    ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add the html, css, and javascript?